# KornShell Error 0403-004 Specify a parameter with this command

Tags: shell, scripting, ksh

This KornShell code is throwing the following error:

**test.ksh**

```
#! /usr/bin/ksh

if [ ${fooVariable} = "" ]; then
    fooVariable="fooString"
fi

echo "${fooVariable}"
```

**Error:**

```
@:/tmp #./test.ksh
./test.ksh[3]: test: 0403-004 Specify a parameter with this command.
```

Why is this error being thrown and how to fix it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Solution:**

Put double quotes around variable.

**test.ksh**

```
#! /usr/bin/ksh

if [ "${fooVariable}" = "" ]; then
    fooVariable="fooString"
fi

echo "${fooVariable}"
```

**Output:**

```
@:/tmp #./test.ksh
fooString
```

Comment: Also you can use the special syntax that ksh provides for setting default values. `var1_with_default=${var1:=bar}; echo $var1_with_default`